# What happened to Arrowverse Chas Chandler (Constantine's friend)?

Tags: dc, arrowverse, arrow, legends-of-tomorrow, constantine

We've seen Constantine coming back as an active Arrowverse character in recent episodes of Legends of Tomorrow (starting from S3E10). Do we know what happened to Chas, his resuscitating friend from the previous series ?

I think Chas' absence from previous sightings of Constantine in Arrow could be explained by the situations not requiring his presence at the time, but now that John is fighting a big villain, it would be quite logical, if nothing happened to him, to see him help the team as well.

Comment: It would be better for you to mention his complete name - ***Chas Chandler***. Because most of us might get him confused with DA Chase (because remember, we haven't seen him on tv since the early 2015; that's 3 years)

Comment: Good point, corrected, thanks !

Comment: I found something that might completely answer your question. Watch CW's Constantine: City of Demons. Its an animated series that is set after the events of Constantine S01 and before all his arrowverse appearances.

Answer (score 2):

I’ve seen all of the Arrowverse shows featuring Constantine, and so far there has been no significant mention of Chas.

This could mean he’s off doing adventures with Zed Martin (Angélica Celaya), that he’s finally dead, or - the idea I lean towards - that the Arrowverse Constantine is from
a different universe to Constantine’s Constantine.

The latter would explain why Constantine has a cheap apartment in New York, and not a magical cabin in the woods, and Manny isn’t hassling him and doing that thing he was planning to do.

EDIT: I have not seen any of the *Constantine: City of Demons* web series, which Chas appears in. However, I don’t know if that’s part of the Arrowverse or not.

An “out of universe” reason for the lack of Chas is likely CW simply doesn’t have the budget to pay for a Chas and Constantine’s cabin.

EDIT 2: According to one of its producers, Peter Girardi, *City of Demons* is a [follow-up to the DC Animated movie Justice League Dark](https://www.cbr.com/wondercon-john-constantine-returns-to-the-arrowverse/). So right now, Chas isn't in the Arrowverse.